# C fork(), wait4() issue

Tags: c, linux, fork

I'm trying to time a `fork`'ed process with `wait4`, however the rusage return value is consistently zero for both `stime` and `utime`.  I've verified that the process is being `fork`'ed properly, `exec`'d properly, and the rusage value is sane (`>0`) when I `exec` a test process which solely eats up clock cycles for a few seconds.

I suspect that the resolution of the clock being used is insufficient to properly time the short process, however a) I get a response of `1ns` for ALL `clockid_t` types queried, and b) I can't see any way to specify which clock should be used for `wait4()`.

Here is my code:

```
double spawnprocess(char *arg1, char *arg2){
  struct rusage usage;
  struct timeval time;
  double t1 = 0.0;
  int nogo;
  pid_t pid;
  char* args[] = { "/path/to/process", arg1, arg2, (char *) 0 };

  do {
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) { printf("Error forking... trying again.\n"); sleep(1); }
  } while (pid == -1);

  if (pid == 0) {
    if ((nogo=execv(args[0], args)) == -1) printf("Error starting new process.\n");
  } else {
    printf("Waiting for child %d...\n", pid);
    int status;
    int options = 0;
    pid_t cpid = wait4(pid, &status, options, &usage);
    if (cpid != pid) {
      printf("Error: %d\n", cpid);
      int tmp;
      if (WIFEXITED(status)) printf("%s", "WIFEXITED");
      if ((tmp = WEXITSTATUS(status))) printf("WEXITSTATUS: %d", tmp);
      if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) printf("%s", "WIFSIGNALED");
      if ((tmp = WTERMSIG(status))) printf("WTERMSIG: %d", tmp);
      if (WCOREDUMP(status)) printf("%s", "Core dumped.");
      if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) printf("%s", "WIFSTOPPED");
      if (WSTOPSIG(status)) printf("%s", "WSTOPSIG");
      if (WIFCONTINUED(status)) printf("%s", "WIFCONTINUED");
    }  else {
      t1 = (usage.ru_utime.tv_sec + (usage.ru_utime.tv_usec/1000000.0));
    }
  }
printf("Sent value is: %e\n", t1);
return t1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The system timers *may* have nanosecond resolution but you'll need a system designed for real-time operation to get out of your way sufficiently that you could see that sort of timing resolution.  I tried your code on non-Linux systems I have here.  And old FreeBSD system running on a Pentium III would  print 0 sometimes and 4e-03 other times.  More recent PowerPC and Intel Macs print numbers in the 4e-05 to 2e-04 range.